What is the semidirect product we use in Levi Decomposition
So using the Levi Decomposition for any lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, there exists a semisimple subalgebra $\mathfrak{s}$ such that:
$Rad(\mathfrak{g})$$\ltimes$$\mathfrak{s}$=$\mathfrak{g}$
However in the proofs I've seen of this, I never get what the semidirect product is? In other words, what is the derivation we are using here?
Could someone explain this to me, thaks in advance.

Levi and Lie (not Levi and lie).

$Rad(\mathfrak g)$ is an ideal; the only derivation in sight, and the only way that $\mathfrak{s}$ can act on this, is the adjoint action.
Formally, take
$$\pi: \mathfrak s \rightarrow Der(Rad(\mathfrak g))\\
s \mapsto ad(s)_{\lvert Rad(\mathfrak g)}$$

$\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{s}\cong \mathfrak{g}/\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$ is semisimple with the multiplication
$$
[X+\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g}),Y+\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})]=[X,Y]+\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g}).
$$
The semisimplicity of $\mathfrak{s}$ results from
$$
\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{s})=\operatorname{Rad}\left(\mathfrak{g}/\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})\right) = \operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})/\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g}) = \{0\}.
$$

That's all correct but not an answer to the OP's question.

Then I didn't get it. Is he looking for the embedding?

What I am asking is when you have a semidirect product, it is always with respect to a specific derivation, right? In this case what is that derivatoin?

@Albi Do you mean $$[(X,R),(Y,S))]=([X,Y],[R,S]+X.S-Y.R)=([X,Y],[R,S]+[X,S]-[Y,R])$$? It is simply the inherited multiplication from $\mathfrak{g}.$ It is basically what I wrote.

Ohhh ok, thank you so much! I thought it could be a more complicated action for $X.S$ and $Y.R$ than the adjoint one.

@Albi I could give you some more complicated examples, but they are more an "outer" product, a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with a subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}(g).$

Yes, exactly. But I was more interested in knowing the specific product used in Levi decomposition, which is the internal one from what you have said, right?

@Albi Right. The perspective depends on what you have given: $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$ or $\mathfrak{s}$ and $\operatorname{Rad}(\mathfrak{g})$, and I think really difficult would be $\mathfrak{s}$ and $\mathfrak{g}.$
